# Storing rails code in database. Upgraded from Rails 2 to Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql, pg

I have the following piece of code illustrated as below. Was working in my Rails 2 application but having upgraded to Rails 3 it not longer works.

When I render this code, I'm getting like,

```
    <%= radio_button <%= text_field "submission_data", :size => 40 %>
        "submission_data", "first_application", "team_lead" %>
```

Here is my code in view file,

```
    <%= form_for @submission, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @submission}, 
    :html => {:id => "submission_form", :name => 'submission_form_name'} do |f|%>

  <%= render :inline => @submission.cycle.seeker_form, 
             :locals => { :submission_data => @submission_data } %>
```

We're using pg as a back-end support.

Comment: Try calling raw on the inner method. Rails 3 automatically escapes html, so you must tell it not to escape using raw method.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply. I solved this error by removing

        "<" + "%" %> 

code from

        <td><%= "<" + "%" %> if @submission_data.team_lead == "first_applicant" %>Yes<%= "<" + "%" %> else %>No<%= "<" + "%" %> end %></td>

in db/migrate/init_fixture/forms.yml file.